# Modify Active Test traffic exposure

Tags: experience-optimization

I am running a few `A/B test` in `Sitecore 8.2` (production environment) and it is configured with 50% traffic exposure as part of a POC setup. After presenting a interim test reports to the stakeholders, the intention now is to increase the traffic exposure to 100% to speed up the results.

Problem is I can't find a way in `Sitecore Experience Editor` to modify existing running tests. I did spotted that in `/sitecore/system/Marketing Control Panel/Test Lab/mytestname` the active tests would be protected and there is a field for traffic allocation.

Does anyone know if there is a proper way to modify existing tests or if it is okay to modify directly in `/sitecore/system/Marketing Control Panel/Test Lab/mytestname`

[image: Sitecore Backend]

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, what you described is how you have to make that change.  I had the same issue with test strategy and asked support about it.  This was their response.

*The expected way to change the test strategy or traffic allocation is to start the test, unprotect the test item, make your changes and publish the changes.
One additional note: a client may need to close current session for applying a new strategy behavior.*